# Nativescript Audio and Video channels

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I am new to nativescript was wondering if there are any plugins that would stream audio and video data just like we have navigator.getmedia on browser.

Use case being i am trying to implement voice security(not recognition) and facial recognition using tensorflow

Comment: In which format you are streaming your video? I think [nativescript-videoplayer](https://github.com/nstudio/nativescript-videoplayer) work with most common file formats.

Comment: Hi Manoj, appreciate your quick response, but i am not looking to stream a video i just need my app to access device cam and use the output from cam to perform some tasks like skeletal movement face recognition etc.

Comment: Then find plugin designed for camera access, e.g. https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-camera

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are already using tensorflow for machine learning part, if you are looking for just the camera access to capture a picture / video, you could use [nativescript-camera](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-camera) or [nativescript-videorecorder](https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-videorecorder).

There is also [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/blob/master/docs/ML_KIT.md#features), their ML Kit already supports face detection.

Comment: Thanks Manoj, i used tensor flow to create some solution related to security on browser and i wanted to create the same on app too. Will check the options you have posted